# How to display RANK in mysql table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

If we have rank depends on two column, lets say score and time,
and i want rank on highest score and lowest time.

```
CREATE TABLE yourTable (id int, userid int, questions int, `date` varchar(10),
                        rightquestions int, examid int, `time` int);
INSERT INTO yourTable (id, userid, questions, `date`, rightquestions, examid, `time`)
VALUES
    (1, 10, 5, '02/09/2017', 5, 2, 11),
    (2, 12, 5, '02/09/2017', 5, 2, 11),
    (9, 16, 5, '02/09/2017', 4, 2, 18),
    (8, 15, 5, '02/09/2017', 3, 2, 18);
```

as you can see above,In my table score = rightanswers and time=time

Now if i want rank by Highest rightanswers and lowest time then what should be the query?

I tried this one but getting unexpected results

```
SELECT id, rightquestions, leagueid,time,
CASE 
WHEN @prevRank = rightquestions AND @prevTime != time THEN @curRank  
WHEN @prevRank != rightquestions AND @prevTime != time THEN @curRank 
WHEN @prevRank := rightquestions AND @prevTime := time AND @curRank = 0 THEN @curRank := @curRank + 1
END AS rank
FROM results p,
(SELECT @curRank :=0, @prevRank := NULL, @prevTime := NULL) r
ORDER BY rightquestions DESC,time ASC
```

Comment: What is your question?  Please supply sample data and desired results.

Comment: Where does this question come from? What are the "above queries" you reference?

Comment: Hello sorry for my bad description, I just uploaded my table's screen shot, i need rank for highest 'rightanserws' and lowest 'time'

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate a dense rank in MySQL by using a row number session variable along with a subquery which identifies unique `rightquestions`/`time` pairs.  Try the following query which is based off the table snapshot you shared with us:

```
SET @row_number = 0;

SELECT t1.rightquestions, t1.`time`, t2.rank
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS rank, t.rightquestions, t.`time`
    FROM
    (
        SELECT rightquestions, `time`
        FROM yourTable
        GROUP BY rightquestions, `time`
    ) t
    ORDER BY t.rightquestions DESC, t.`time`
) t2
    ON t1.rightquestions = t2.rightquestions AND
       t1.`time`  = t2.`time`
```

Here is the output I got in Workbench while testing locally:

```
rightquestions | time | rank
5              | 11   | 1
5              | 11   | 1
4              | 18   | 2
3              | 18   | 3
```

Comment: hello thank you for quick reply, i edited the question and put a screen shot of my table, actually we do not have rank in our table

Comment: @JaymitGhadiya You are not reading/understanding my query.  My query computes the rank for each score and time combination.

Comment: Actully i tried you query in my table screen shot i uploaded in description. like this                                                                                SET @row_number = 0;

SELECT t.rightquestions, t.time, t.rank
FROM results t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS rank, rightquestions, time
    FROM results
    GROUP BY rightquestions, time
    ORDER BY rightquestions DESC, time
) t2
    ON t1.rightquestions = t2.rightquestions AND
       t1.time  = t2.time

Comment: you see the difference.?

Answer (score 0):

You require a session variable that will increase and restart every time the score changes. You can also initialize it in a "fake" join, within the actual query as follows:

```
select timer, if(@score = score,@rank:=@rank+1,@rank:= 1) as rank ,@score:=score as score
from (
      select 1 score, now() + interval rand()*10 hour as timer
      union all
      select 1 score, now() + interval rand()*10 hour as timer
      union all
      select 2 score, now() + interval rand()*10 hour as timer
      union all
      select 3 score, now() + interval rand()*10 hour as timer
      union all
      select 3 score, now() + interval rand()*10 hour as timer
)
 t
 join (select @rank:=0, @score := 0)r on (1=1) 
 order by score, timer asc
```

Comment: hello thank you for quick reply, i edited the question and put a screen shot of my table, actually we do not have rank in our table